# How to translate behaviours from xaml to c#

Tags: c#, xaml, behavior

I’d like to reuse this behaviour, and it cannot be put in any kind of resource dictionary or style as recently found out. So what I’d like to try is to translate it to c#, so I’d like to inherit from grid and add this behaviour to it if possible. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is the xaml

```
 <Grid >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding KeepAlive}"
                              FalseState="InactiveState"
                              TrueState="ActiveState"
                              Value="False" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="ActiveState" />
            <VisualState x:Name="InactiveState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                     Storyboard.TargetName="ActiveContainer" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsEnabled)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="InactiveContainer" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  </Grid >
```

Thank you

**EDIT** 
I just want to do it, because this behaviour does exactly what I need. But there is so many places I use it, and I have to keep adding it for every single grid, I want to have one kind of Grid which does it by default.

Comment: @Shekhar I tried to move this code to style, so I could just do Grid Style ={ Static resource} and that code would be in style. This does not work, so I thought I create a usercontrol and stick that Grid inside it and then just use the user control, but then I had an error that I cant use names for the stuff i want to wrapp up in that user control. So now I tought I try it in c#, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, procedural code is not the right way to do it. You have an  XY  problem here.  The solution is not to fall back to procedural code, but instead find a proper XAML based solution for the underlying root problem.

Comment: Not sure why this needs to be a behavior if I'm reading the intent right honestly. Why not just make KeepAlive a public bool (which it looks like it is already, and just bind it to visibility of the control? Something like adding `Visibility="{Binding KeepAlive, Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}"` and vice versa for the IsEnabled property?

Comment: @ChrisW. I just want to do it, because this behaviour does exactly what I need. But there is so many places I use it, and I have to keep adding it for every single grid that I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This style is to maintain a state for the control to be enabled or disabled and to simply switch the state when conditions change.

By *expressing* this as a Boolean `InotifyProperty` change value property on the viewmodel bound to the `IsEnabled` of the target control is all that is needed.

Then switching the value in code behind or even in Xaml can be accomplished regardless of factors.

### Update

Since you mentioned that the grid/style is reused in many places, create a custom User Control which builds off of the grid and has the style built within it. That way all of the style cues (such as the one shown) can be centralized into the new grid and seamlessly dropped (reused) into other xaml pages.

Comment: Please see my Edit section.

Comment: @adminSoftDK If this is reused, simply create a user control which encapsulates the style and can be reused elsewhere. See my update.

Comment: I've tried it and I get this error Cannot add content to object of type '.CustomControl1'. This Grid has then the content which is different on different screens. So I need to be able to add the content to it, but I want that behaviour for when it is active or inactive.